# how to set mouse position (pageX,pageY) in webview of android?

Tags: android, webview

I want to manually set cursor position (pageX,pageY) in a Webview of android, anyone know how?
Scrollto is not good for the following case:

I use [FLVPlayer.swf](http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0/) (http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0/) in a webview to play flv. But the player interface is visible when the mouse is hovering over it and otherwise invisible, this way does not work for mobile phone (Android phone with touch screen, the player interface always shows). So I wondering how to hide the interface.